# Trouble with Wishlist for e-commerse project

Tags: angular

Now I'm working on project when i click an icon 'fa-heart' first it supposed to be solid and be added to wishlist and when i click again it turns regular and be removed from wishlist
i've tried first it turned the fa-heart of all products together , I've tried. with multiple ways and failed
How to make it according to the id of the product that check whether it exist in the wishlist ?

I want when i open the page the icon of products that exist in the wishlist already to be solid and to toggle when i click
*I'm new to angular and this my first full project

```
import { Product } from './../../interfaces/data';
import { Data } from '../../interfaces/data';
import { Component, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlOptions } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { elementAt } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  
  // togglePanel: any = {};
  activeIndex: number = -1;
  products: any[] = [];
  inWishList: boolean = false;
  resWishList: any;
  resCart: any;
  curretItem: any[] = []
  wishData: any[] = []
  element: any[] = []

  constructor(private _ProductsService: ProductsService, private toastr: ToastrService, private render: Renderer2) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getproducts()
    this.getWishlist()
    this.isInWishlist(this.curretItem)
  }

  getWishlist() {
    this._ProductsService.getWishList().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        // console.log(res);
        this.wishData = res.data
        // this.wishlist = res.data.id
        console.log();
        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        }
      }
    });
  }
  getproducts() {
    this._ProductsService.getProducts().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        this.products = res.data
      },
      error: () => {
      }, complete: () => {
      }
    })
  }
  addToWishList(id: any) {
    this._ProductsService.addWishList(id).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.resWishList = res;
        this.curretItem = id
        this.element = res.data;
        // for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        let element = res.data
        console.log(this.element.indexOf(this.curretItem));

      }, error: () => {

      },
      complete: () => {

        this.toastr.success(this.resWishList.status, this.resWishList.message);
      }
    })
  }
  removeFromWishlist(id: any) {
    this._ProductsService.removeWishlistItemUser(id).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.resWishList = res;
        this.curretItem = id
        this.element = res.data;
        console.log(this.element);

      }, error: () => {
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.toastr.error(this.resWishList.status, 'Product removed successfully from your wishlist');
      }
    })
  }
  isInWishlist(curretItem: any) {
    curretItem = ''
    console.log(this.curretItem);
    console.log(this.wishData);

    if (this.wishData.indexOf(this.curretItem) !== -1) {
      this.inWishList = true;
      let product = document.querySelector('.fa-heart') as HTMLElement;
      product.classList.add('fa-solid');
      product.classList.remove('fa-regular');
      console.log(this.curretItem);
      console.log(this.wishData);
    }
    else {
      let product = document.querySelector('.fa-heart') as HTMLElement;
      product.classList.remove('fa-solid');
      product.classList.add('fa-regular');
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 overflow-hidden" *ngFor="let product of products ; let i = index; ">
      <div class="product px-2">
        <button class="btn" (click)="isInWishlist(product._id)">
          <i  class="fa-heart fa-regular"
            ></i>
          <!-- <i  class=" fa-heart "
            [class]="!inWishList? 'fa-regular':'fa-solid'"></i> -->
        </button>
        <a [routerLink]="['/productsDetailes',product._id]">
          <img [src]="product.imageCover" class="w-100 rounded-1" alt="">
          <span class="text-main fw-bold font-sm">{{product.category.name}}</span>
          <h3 class="fs-6 my-1 text-dark">{{product.title.split(' ').slice(0,2).join(' ')}}</h3>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-products-center font-sm">
            <span class="text-muted ">{{product.price}} EGP</span>
            <span><i class="fa-solid fa-star rating-color"></i> {{product.ratingsAverage}}</span>

          </div>
        </a>
        <button (click)="addToCart(product._id)" class="btn bg-main text-white my-2 w-100">+ Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it but had another problem it goes unchecked when I refresh , and by clicking again all items that exist in wishlist go to solid

So how wishlisted items remain solid after refreshing

`

```
 <!-- language: lang-js -->

import { Product } from './../../interfaces/data';
import { Data } from '../../interfaces/data';
import { Component, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlOptions } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {

  products: Product[] = [];
  resWishList: any;
  resCart: any;
  wishData: any[] = []
  selectedId: any;
  inWishlist: any[] = []
  constructor(private _ProductsService: ProductsService, private toastr: 
ToastrService) { 

    
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getproducts()
    this.getWishlist()
  }
  getWishlist() {
    this._ProductsService.getWishList().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        this.wishData = res.data
        this.inWishlist = this.wishData
        console.log(this.inWishlist);
      }
    });
  }
  getproducts() {
    this._ProductsService.getProducts().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        this.products = res.data
      },
      error: () => {
      },
      complete: () => {
      }
    })
  }
  isInWishlist(id: any) {
    this._ProductsService.getWishList().subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.resWishList = res.data;
        let result = this.resWishList.find((el: { _id: any; }) => el._id 
        == id)
        if (result == undefined) {
          this._ProductsService.addWishList(id).subscribe({
            next: (res: any) => {
              this.resWishList = res
              console.log(this.resWishList.data);
              this.selectedId = id
              this.inWishlist = this.resWishList.data
              // if (this.resWishList.data.indexOf(id) >= 0) {
              // }
            },
            error: () => {
            },
            complete: () => {
              this.toastr.success(this.resWishList.status, 
       this.resWishList.message);
            }
          })
        }
        else {
          this._ProductsService.removeWishlistItemUser(id).subscribe({
            next: (res: any) => {
              this.resWishList = res;
              this.inWishlist = this.resWishList.data
              this.selectedId = " "
              console.log(this.resWishList.data);

              // if (this.resWishList.data.indexOf(id) >= -1) {
              // }
            }
            , error: () => {

            },
            complete: () => {
              this.toastr.error(this.resWishList.status, 'Product 
    removed successfully from your wishlist');
              // this.toastr.success('success', 'Product added 
  successfully to your wishlist');
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 overflow-hidden" *ngFor="let product of products ">
      <div class="product px-2">
        <button class="btn">
          <i  class="fa-heart " [class]="inWishlist.includes(product._id)? 'fa-solid' : 'fa-regular'"
            (click)="isInWishlist(product._id)"></i>
          <!-- <i *ngIf="!inWishlist.includes(product._id)" class="fa-heart fa-regular" 
            (click)="isInWishlist(product._id)"></i> -->
        </button>
        <a [routerLink]="['/productsDetailes',product._id]">
          <img [src]="product.imageCover" class="w-100 rounded-1" alt="">
          <span class="text-main fw-bold font-sm">{{product.category.name}} </span>
          <h3 class="fs-6 my-1 text-dark">{{product.title.split(' ').slice(0,2).join(' ')}}</h3>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-products-center font-sm">
            <span class="text-muted ">{{product.price}} EGP</span>
            <span><i class="fa-solid fa-star rating-color"></i> {{product.ratingsAverage}}</span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <button (click)="addToCart(product._id)" class="btn bg-main text-white my-2 w-100">+ Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```